# MultiSelect Widget doesn't remove pre-selected options with this 'open' function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, multi-select

When I add this function, the [jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) no longer removes a pre-selected option when it's unselected. How can I get this function to work without losing the ability to unselect an option?

A fiddle demonstrating the problem is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/Mp2bK/10/

JS

```
$(function () {   
    $(".example").multiselect({
        open: function (event, ui) {
            var option = $(this).find("option[value*=default]");
            option.attr('value', option.attr('value').replace(/_default/g, ''));
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<select name="example" class="example" multiple="multiple">  
    <option value="0">$0</option>
    <option value="50_default" selected="selected">$50</option>
    <option value="100">$100</option>
</select>
```

I am pre-selecting the most commonly chosen options for apx. 300 Select elements, and am using this function in order to differentiate between when those values are still in their initial pre-selected/default state vs. when a user has actively chosen that value by clicking on the form element (indicating that they made an active decision to leave it set to that value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, you can use the refresh method to make sure it is update.

I added

```
$(".example").multiselect("refesh")
```

To the form submit

[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oumichaelm/Mp2bK/11/)

Comment: Thank you so much :-D The form submit function was just for the fiddle (since it allowed me to view the value that would be submitted) so I moved it to the 'open' function and it's working perfectly :-D